# Is inequality $tr(A^{-1^T} B) tr(A^T B^{-1}) \leq constant$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have the following optimization problem 
\begin{align}
\min_{A} &tr(A^{-1^T} B)\cr
\text{subject to}  &x^T A x > 0 \cr
& A_{ii}=1
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ are some positive definite matrices. Is the above problem is equivalent to the following problem: 
\begin{align}
\max_{A} &trace(A^T B^{-1})\cr
\text{subject to}  &x^T A x > 0\cr
& A_{ii}=1
\end{align}
In other words is this inequality $ tr(A^{-1^T} B) tr(A^T B^{-1}) \leq c$ where $c$ is some constant, is correct? 
And finaly what if $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite and we replace inverse with pesudo inverse?

Comment: It means $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: The hypothesis fails even for $2\times2$ diagonal matrices. You'll have a lower bound for the product, but no upper bound.

Comment: could you explain a little more. and what is the lower bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $X={A^{-1}}^T B$ where I assume $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ positive definite matrices. Then, $X$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n>0$, and the trace $\text{tr}(X)=\sum_j\lambda_j$.

The constraint $A_{ii}=1$ (added after my original answer) have very little impact on the eigenvalues, and so I'll ignore them.

Since $\text{tr}(UV)=\text{tr}(VU)$ for all matrices $U$ and $V$ (of appropriate dimensions),
$$
\text{tr}(A^TB^{-1})=\text{tr}(X^{-1})=\sum_j\frac{1}{\lambda_j}.
$$
Thus, the product of the traces becomes
$$
\text{tr}(X)\cdot\text{tr}(X^{-1})
=\sum_i\lambda_i\cdot\sum_j\frac{1}{\lambda_j}
\ge n^2.
$$

To see that there is no upper bound, for example let $X$ be a diagonal $2\times2$ matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $u$. Then, the product of the traces becomes $(1+u)(1+1/u)=2+u+1/u$ which can get arbitrary large as $u\rightarrow0^+$ or $u\rightarrow\infty$.

If we require that $A_{ii}=1$, we can still force large variations in the eigenvalues: e.g., $A=\pmatrix{1&u\\ u&1}$ with $u>1$.

In order to obtain an upper bound, it would be necessary to place constraints that limit the ratio between the largest and smallest eigenvalues. An upper bound on the eigenvalues of $X$ could for example be added by demanding that $\text{tr}(X)\le C$ for some fixed $C$; or $|X|^2=\text{tr}(X^TX)\le C$. Lower bounds on the eigenvalues may be placing similar restrictions on $X^{-1}$.

Instead of placing the bounds on $X$ and $X^{-1}$, I think it should be sufficient to place similar bound on $A$, $A^{-1}$, $B$, and $B^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you.why there isn't an upper bound?

Comment: E.g., let $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=u$. If $u\rightarrow0^+$ or $u\rightarrow\infty$, the product $(1+u)(1+1/u)$ of the traces diverges.

Comment: if we have a constraints like $ A_{ii}=1$ does it now has some upper bounds?

Comment: That's far from enough to bound the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you edit your answer to contain this constraints. Actually I didn't think it helps  to mention it in the question. so, I will edit it.